# WindsorContainer Construction Error and Logging Issue

Tags: logging, castle-windsor, construction

I'm using Castle windsor, and initiating it using a configuration file (and really want to keep everything there), which also holds a logging facility.

When I get an error from the windsor on initialization (due to wrong configuration, missing dependencies etc.), I don't have a logger initiated and therefore - can't write the error anywhere...Here's my code:

```
    private static ILogger m_Logger { get; set; } 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Windsor has missing dependencies
            var container = new WindsorContainer("windsor.xml");
            // Did not make it here...
            var logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>();
            m_Logger.Debug("Testing 123");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Logger was not initialized, null reference exception!
            m_Logger.Debug("Testing 123");
        }
    }
```

What are my options here?

Thanks,
Nir.

Comment: What type of application are you running? ASP.NET? Win Forms? How are you deploying your app. On your server? On client machines?

Comment: When you misconfigured your application, you should find out during testing or staging, but nonetheless, you don't need to catch and log, since your application will not start and you can see the stack trace when accessing the service locally.

Comment: @Steven Not true. At least in some situations, you just get `null` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can write to the Windows Event log:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    const string Source = "MySource";
    const string Log = "MyNewLog";

    // Create the source, if it does not already exist.
    if(!EventLog.SourceExists(Source))
    {
        EventLog.CreateEventSource(Source , Log);
    }

    // Create an EventLog instance and assign its source.
    EventLog myLog = new EventLog();
    myLog.Source = Source;

    string eventMessage = string.Empty;

    while (ex != null)
    {
        eventMessage += string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n\n",
            ex.GetType().FullName,
            ex.Message,
            ex.SackTrace);
    }

    myLog.WriteEntry(eventMessage);
}
```

Comment: I would really like to have this in the log, or at least have the option to write it to the event log via log4net windsor facility. Any way around that?

Comment: Well, if your logger isn't configured right, there is no way to use it. If it is configured right, you can simply call the log4net logging facade. There is no problem doing that inside your composition root.

Answer (score 0):

This really eats up all expectations of using an IOC container in the first place. 
Anyway you can create your logger (Ex: log4net) manually at the catch block, and log it.

```
...
catch (Exception)
{
    // Create logger here
    m_Logger = new Log4NetLogger(); // Assuming 'windsor.xml' configured to inject a Log4NetLogger
    m_Logger.Debug("Testing 123");
}
```